# Checking for null in flatmap

Tags: scala, scope, null

I have a Neo4J query that returns a list of nodes that most likely wont be empty, but in some cases could return null. How can I check for a null result within a map or flatmap operation?

```
 val nodes = {
    storeAPI.NeoQuery(parentNodesIDs).resultList().map {
      _.flatMap {
        record =>
          record.get("assetList").asList.asScala.map(_.toString).toSet
      }
    }.recover {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"Failure in getSimplifiedAssetListFromContainer: ", e)
        throw e
    }
  }
```

I have tried to take the `storeAPI.NeoQuery(parentNodeIDs).resultList()` into a `val` outside of the above block, but then `val nodes` goes out of scope.

`val nodes = {...}` is of type `Future[List[String]]`

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `flatMap(Option(_))` like so

```
record
  .get("assetList")
  .asList
  .asScala
  .flatMap(Option(_))
  .map(_.toString)
  .toSet
```

For example

```
List(1,null,3).flatMap(Option(_)).map(_.toString).foreach(println)
```

outputs

```
1
3
```

This works because `Option(null)` is `None`, and `None`s get discarded by `flatMap`.